# Package not found - add libav to PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, libav, pkg-config

I am attempting to build the Parrot SDK and when running the command it continuously fails due to multiple libav package variants not being found. Below is the error message.

```
user@TheMysteriousMachine:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ ./build.sh -p arsdk-native -t build-sdk -j
    [I] Starting task 'build-sdk'
    [I] In '/home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY':   ALCHEMY_TARGET_CONFIG_DIR="/home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/products/arsdk  /native/config" ALCHEMY_TARGET_OUT="/home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/arsdk-native" ALCHEMY_TARGET_PRODUCT="arsdk" ALCHEMY_TARGET_PRODUCT_VARIANT="native" ALCHEMY_TARGET_SCAN_ADD_DIRS=" /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/packages" ALCHEMY_TARGET_SCAN_PRUNE_DIRS=" /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY" ALCHEMY_USE_COLORS="1" ALCHEMY_WORKSPACE_DIR="/home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_GROUP="drones" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_PRODUCT="arsdk" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_PROJECT="arsdk" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_UID="arsdk-native-20190316-1404-0.0.0" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_VARIANT="native" PARROT_BUILD_PROP_VERSION="0.0.0" /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/build/alchemy/scripts/alchemake -j 8 all
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    + ALCHEMY_WORKSPACE_DIR = /home/user /WORKING_DIRECTORY
    + TARGET_PRODUCT = arsdk
    + TARGET_PRODUCT_VARIANT = native
    + TARGET_OS = linux
    + TARGET_OS_FLAVOUR = native
    + TARGET_LIBC = native
    + TARGET_ARCH = x64
    + TARGET_CPU = 
    + TARGET_OUT = /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/arsdk-native
    + TARGET_CONFIG_DIR = /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY /products/arsdk/native/config
    + TARGET_CC_PATH = /usr/bin/cc
    + TARGET_CC_VERSION = 7
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Scanning /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/packages for makefiles...
    Found 44 makefiles
    Prebuilt module ncurses marked as overriden
    Prebuilt module ncurses marked as overriden
    Package libavcodec was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing libavcodec.pc&apos;
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package &apos;libavcodec&apos; found
    Package libavformat was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containinglibavformat.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libavformat' found
    Package libswscale was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing libswscale.pc&apos;
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package &apos;libswscale&apos; found
    Package libavutil was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containinglibavutil.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libavutil' found
    Package libavcodec was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing libavcodec.pc&apos;
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package &apos;libavcodec&apos; found
    Package libavformat was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containinglibavformat.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libavformat' found
    Package libswscale was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing libswscale.pc&apos;
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package &apos;libswscale&apos; found
    Package libavutil was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containinglibavutil.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libavutil' found
    Found 96 modules
    Computing modules dependencies...
    Checking modules dependencies...
    /home/user/WORKING_DIRECTORY/build/alchemy/main.mk:360: *** /home/user    /WORKING_DIRECTORY/packages/libARDiscovery: module 'libARDiscovery'     depends on unknown module 'avahi'.  Stop.
    [E] Task 'build-sdk' failed (Command     failed (returncode=2))
```

As I understand it libav has been replaced by ffmpeg but the build should     still be able to reference the packages as libav. I've tried adding different paths to PKG_CONFIG_PATH using `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=...' but with no success. It is possible I'm not adding the correct path, I used 'dpkg -L ffmpeg' to locate the package. The output of that is:

```
user@TheMysteriousMachine:~$ dpkg -L ffmpeg
    /.
    /etc
    /etc/ffserver.conf
    /usr
    /usr/bin
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg
    /usr/bin/ffplay
    /usr/bin/ffprobe
    /usr/bin/ffserver
    /usr/bin/qt-faststart
    /usr/share
    /usr/share/doc
    /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg
    /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/RELEASE_NOTES
    /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/copyright
    /usr/share/ffmpeg
    /usr/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-1080p.ffpreset
    /usr/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset
    /usr/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-360p.ffpreset
    /usr/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-720p.ffpreset
    /usr/share/ffmpeg/libvpx-720p50_60.ffpreset
    /usr/share/lintian
    /usr/share/lintian/overrides
    /usr/share/lintian/overrides/ffmpeg
    /usr/share/man
    /usr/share/man/man1
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-all.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-codecs.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-devices.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-filters.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-formats.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-protocols.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-resampler.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-scaler.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg-utils.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffmpeg.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffplay-all.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffplay.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffprobe-all.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffprobe.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffserver-all.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/ffserver.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/qt-faststart.1.gz
    /usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/changelog.Debian.gz
```

...of which I can assume the useful part is '/usr/bin' which i added to my PKG_CONFIG_PATH and still the same error when building. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm at a loss and have been grinding at this for the past 2 days, any help would be  **GREATLY**  appreciated. Thank you and I'm happy to provide more needed information. As a small request, I am pretty new to Linux so if you could include as many details in command line operations as possible it would help *alot*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you followed FFmpeg Ubuntu compilation guidelines here:https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

The path you looking for must be here: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig`